# Protect BIOS from very aggressive program

Tags: assembly, bios, data-protection, real-mode

For the sake of experiment, I plan to run program X in realmode.

Program X will make a random routine, and execute it (I want to see what will happen).

But I worry that this program eventually damages the BIOS permanently.

Is there a way to protect the BIOS from this aggressive program?

Comment: Use a virtual machine.

Comment: @Jester Thanks for your comment. I wonder if I can protect bios in real hardware. Will you share more about your knowledge?

Comment: What is protecting the BIOS? For example, a stray write to a random sector in the disk won't damage the BIOS but may be very annoying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As @Jester suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588670/protect-bios-from-very-aggressive-program#comment68412900_40588670), just use a virtual machine. DOSBox, Bochs, and maybe QEMU are nice for 16-bit emulation. Because, if you are really unlucky (I don't know what exactly you mean with "random," though) you might end up with a corrupted CMOS, a flashed BIOS, or other corrupted hardware. In Real Mode, anything is possible, so running on a real machine might lead to serious damage.

You might also try writing a Protected Mode wrapper and run the code in Virtual 8086 Mode. Not quite the same as Real Mode, but at least you're not going to destroy your system.